# Integration and dot product

Tags: integration, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable.
We assume that there exists $L > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
   \|∇f(x)-∇f(x')\| \leq  L\|x − x'\| \qquad \forall (x,x') \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}

Show that
\begin{equation}
  |f(x + h) − f(x) − \langle ∇f(x), h\rangle | \leq \frac{L}{2} \|h\|^2 \qquad \forall (x, h) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}

I do not understand part of the demonstration of which here is:

As $f$ is continuously differentiable, we have from Taylor's formula at zero order with residual in integral form
\begin{equation}
  f (x + h) = f(x) + \int^1_0 \langle ∇f(x + th), h \rangle dt. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

---

Me, when I apply Taylor's formula at zero order with residual in integral form, we get
\begin{equation}
  f (x + h) = f(x) + \int_x^{x+h} ∇f(t) dt. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
What is the integration process that allows us to leave (2) to (1) ?

Comment: You forgot the dot product since your $t$ (and hence $\mathrm{d}t$) is $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued as it goes from $x$ to $x+h$.  Now write $\vec{t}=\vec{x}+\tau\vec{h}$ for the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus \begin{aligned}
f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) &= \int_0^1\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h})^T\mathbf{h}\,dt \\
&=\nabla f(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{h}+ \int_0^1\big(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{x})\big)^T\mathbf{h}\,dt 
\end{aligned}
and therefore
\begin{aligned}
|f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x})-\nabla f(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{h}|
&=\Big|\int_0^1\big(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{x})\big)^T\mathbf{h}\,dt \Big|\\
&\leq \int_0^1\big|\big(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{x})\big)^T\mathbf{h}\big|\,dt \\
&\overset{\text{C.S.}}\leq \int_0^1\|\big(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{x})\big)\|\|\mathbf{h}\|\,dt  \\
&\leq\int_0^1tL\|\mathbf{h}\|^2\,dt \\
&\leq \|\mathbf{h}\|^2
\end{aligned}
where C.S. is Cauchy-Schwarz and the inequality following it is from the fact that $f$ is $L$-smooth.

For general knowledge, this inequality is known as the *Descent Lemma*, and it's very useful in convex analysis. Analysis of optimization algorithms strongly relies on the ability to quantify the change in function value when moving from some point $\mathbf{x}$ in a direction $\mathbf{h}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla f(t)$ isn't a number. The output of $f$ is a number, so $f(x+h)$ will surely be a number. That means we must have the thing we integrate be a number! The Taylor's theorem you use is perhaps a naive generalization of the one from single variate calculus, but does not hold in multivariate calculus. The form your text states is the correct generalization.